# Bad logic, MSSQL, Coldfusion, duplicate results from query

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, duplicates, left-join

I've been trying fix this query for over a week, and I can't sem to get it right. Went down a complete rabbit hole that got me close, but kept geting bigger and bigger. So I'd like to start from scratch.

As it was originally written:

```
<cfquery name="unbilledMisc" datasource="#request.dsn#">
SELECT  BM.*, C.Client, U.Name, R.FrequencyUnit, R.FrequencyDuration, R.RBID
FROM BilledMisc BM
    LEFT JOIN Clients C on C.ClientID = BM.ClientID
    LEFT JOIN Users U on U.UserID = BM.UserID
    LEFT JOIN RecurringBilling R ON (R.ClientID = C.ClientID AND BM.Rate = R.Rate AND BM.Title = R.Title)
WHERE (BM.CID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">) 
AND (BM.Invoiced = 0)
ORDER BY BM.DateCompleted ASC;
</cfquery>
```

BM*= BM.BMID, BM.Userid, BM.ClientID, BM.Rate, BM.Title, BM.CID, BM.QTY, BM.DateCompleted

The output row looks like:

```
<td class=""><input type="checkbox" class="BMIDCheckBoxes" name="BMID" value="#BMID#" />#Client#</td>
<td class="">
    <cfif #Qty# eq "">
     -
    <cfelse>
        <a href="##" class="UpdateFeeItem invoices" title="#BMID#">#NumberFormat(Qty, '9999.99')#</a>
    </cfif>
</td>
<td class="">#Name#</td>
<td>
<cfif #RBID# neq ''>
<cfswitch expression="#FrequencyUnit#">
    <cfcase value="d">
        <cfset FreqOutput = 'Day(s)'>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="ww">
        <cfset FreqOutput = 'Week(s)'>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="m">
        <cfset FreqOutput = 'Month(s)'>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="q">
        <cfset FreqOutput = 'Quarter(s)'>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="yyyy">
        <cfset FreqOutput = 'Year(s)'>
    </cfcase>
</cfswitch>
<a href="##" name="#RBID#" id="UpdateRecItem" class="link"><img src="images/edit_icon.png" /></a>
Recurrs Every #FrequencyDuration# #FreqOutput#
</cfif>
</td>
<td class="">#DateFormat(DateCompleted, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
<td style="width:50px;" align="center"><a href="##" class="DeleteFeeItem" title="#BMID#"><img src="images/delete_icon.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" /></a></td>
```

I'm open to any suggestions, on a better way to do this.

You can set up a 1 time fee, or set up a fee that behaves like a one time fee, and then recurs every set interval (day, week, month, quater, year) for the same dollar amount, based on the per unit price and quantity.

If you make just a one time fee, everything is fine.

When you make the first recurring fee, everything is fine.

But lets say 2 weeks go by and 500 other clients. And you're gonna set up another 1 time fee for that client, setup by the same user, for the same product for the same amount, I get a duplicate row, that shares the same RBID with different BMID's

Essentially 1 of those rows has a one time fee that is supposed to recur, and another identical one time fee that thinks it's supposed to recur, and has the RBID of the first row.

If you were a small company you would remember to go in and edit the amount of the first fee, but if you're a big company and don't remember, than they hist this bug.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on any part of this. I'd be happy to.

Edit:
At a risk of going in a different direction, I've also considered adding a new column to the recurring table, that would hold the BMID for each recurring item if one exists. That way I could just reference wich recurring fee belongs to each one time fee by 1 column.

I guess on submit, it would add all of the data to a new row in billedMisc, which creates an auto incremented BMID, then if recurring fee is set add the recurring data in to a new recurringbilling row with the newly created BMID. Which would lock them together by a specific identifier instead of looking at which rate, qty, user,client... match up.

Thoughts... Feelings?

**EDIT: I'm ditching this query in my project and adding a new column to one of the tables to lock it to the fee item**

*Mods feel free to delete if so inclined*

Comment: You're not clearly stating what problem you're having.

Comment: Sorry, I have read this several times and still do not understand what issue you are experiencing :) Is the query returning "duplicates", the output, ...? What are the *actual* results of your code and ... how are they *different* than what you expected. It would also help to see a small data dump as well.

Comment: I edited with more of an explanation. My apologies, I got more focused on making sure all of the info was in there, than what was happening, and what I needed it to do. Thanks for lookng.

Comment: It sounds like you've got your BillingMisc storing some sort of "master" billing record and then you're creating new rows in RecurringBilling each time you set up a "one time fee that's suppose to recur". Is that correct?

Comment: You're joining on values between BillingMisc and RecurringBilling which, from my understanding, seem like they could match multiple times. ClientID, Rate and Title. If there are two records in RecurringBilling with the same sets of values, you'd get multiple records from that join.

Comment: @phantom42, yes you are correct. I've decided to ditch this query, and add a column to my BilledMisc table to store the RBID associated with it. I never liked the way this query was working, so I'm glad to get rid of this.

Comment: You have to be very careful doing multiple OUTER JOINs on each other. It's very easy to return data that you didn't intend to or miss data that should have been returned. LEFT JOINing Clients and RecurringBilling to each other while also LEFT JOINing them both to BilledMisc may not be returning what you expect. Be sure you test these queries very thoroughly. Your query above wouldn't be limiting your data by any of your JOINs, only your two statements in the WHERE clause.

And <nitpick>try to avoid *</nitpick>. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshoot as follows.  Start with:

```
<cfquery name="test">
select BM.cid
from BilledMisc BM
where BM.CID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">) 
and BM.invoiced = 0
```

Then add your first join and run it again.  If the recordcount increases, run some more queries to find out why.

If, at the end of the day, you are going to get multiple rows, see if a "select distinct" eliminates the problem.  If it doesn't, look at the data being returned and decide which record is the one you want.

Comment: Thank you, I will start on this now.